# Best Testing structure

Tags: unit-testing, testing, googletest

I have in mind this 2 approaches regarding testing structure:

 First option

- UnitTest

  - Feature1
  - Feature2
  - etc
- IntegrationTest

  - Feature1
  - Feature2
  - etc 
    ...

Second option:

- Feature 1
- Feature 2
- etc
- cmakeUnitT
- cmakeIntegration

Third option? 
I like the first one because we have each test well divided, but in the second one we have each feature with all it's tests. Is there any advantage to any of it? Is there a better way of organizing tests? (c++, gtest, and mocks everywhere)

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the second option. From the test coverage point of view this is better to see all the tests that covers the specific feature. From the development point of view I would like also to see all the tests together in order to receive fast assessment for what we need to add. From the regression test perspective easy to launch the tests only for the feature that was updated.

Answer (score 1):

i would go for the first option. although it splits tests for the same feature it lets you easier run all unit tests from your IDE - you just select top folder of all unit tests or unit tests for specific feature and run all unit tests. and later you can relaunch them with a single shortcut. and relaunching unit tests is one of the most important and most frequent thing during programming. why it doesn't work so great with integration tests? because they are way slower and often require additional setup

so while second option is more clean and orthodox, the first one is simply more practical

if you have too many 'feature x' folders/files then you can always introduce another level like

- unit tests

  - component 1

    - feature 1
    - feature 2